# Spot the Difference - Count the clicks for lives and next level (scene)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, counter

I am creating a spot the difference game and at the moment, when you click on the difference a box appears on both pictures to highlight the difference. Using a mouse event when clicked on the correct area the box will appear.

I would now like to add a click counter so when the 5 differences have been found it will go to the next scene (next level) How do I do that?

BUT I also would like the game to have 3 lives... so the player cannot just click anywhere on the screen to find the differences (cheat!).. so it would count every time the player clicked the mouse and minus a life on the screen.. and then go to another scene to say - "you lost".

Count clicks =

- Next Level
- Lives

I'd appreciate any help,

Thank you!

My code is below: (using AS3 in Flash)

```
   //Adds an event listener to the button component with the mouse click event.
//eyes
eyebox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject);
eyebox1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject);
one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject);

//skull 
skullbox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject2);
skullbox1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject2);
two.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject2);

//cuffs
cuffbox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject3);
cuffbox1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject3);
three.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject3);

//Initially disable the show button.

//eyes
showeye.enabled = true;
showeye1.enabled = true;
eyebox.visible = false;
eyebox1.visible = false;
one.visible = false;

//skull
showskull.enabled = true;
showskull1.enabled = true;
skullbox.visible = false;
skullbox1.visible = false;
two.visible = false;

//cuffs
showcuffs.enabled = true;
showcuffs1.enabled = true;
cuffbox.visible = false;
cuffbox1.visible = false;
three.visible = false;



//Adds an event listener to the button component with the mouse click event.

showeye.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject);
showeye1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject);

showskull.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject2);
showskull1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject2);

showcuffs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject3);
showcuffs1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject3);



//This function show the movie clip, and disables the show button.
function showObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
eyebox.visible = true;
eyebox1.visible = true;
one.visible = true;
showeye.enabled = true;
showeye1.enabled = true;

}

function showObject2(event:MouseEvent):void {
skullbox.visible = true;
skullbox1.visible = true;
two.visible = true;
showskull.enabled = true;
showskull1.enabled = true;

}

function showObject3(event:MouseEvent):void {
cuffbox.visible = true;
cuffbox1.visible = true;
three.visible = true;
showcuffs.enabled = true;
showcuffs1.enabled = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not even necessary to add event listeners to every object. In my opinion you can add one listener to whole picture ate first:

```
wholePicture.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickListener);
```

And then in clickListener look if user clicked on your object or if he/she missed:

```
function clickListener(e:MouseEvent):void {
   if(showEye.hitTestPoint(e.x, e.y) || showeye1.hitTestPoint(e.x, e.y)){
      showObject();
      ++NextLevelCounter;
   }else if(showSkull.hitTestPoint(e.x, e.y) || showSkull1.hitTestPoint(e.x, e.y)){
      showObject2();
      ++NextLevelCounter;
   }else if(cuffbox.hitTestPoint(e.x, e.y) || cuffbox1.hitTestPoint(e.x, e.y)){
      showObject3();
      ++NextLevelCounter;
   }else{
      --LivesCounter;
   }
   if(NextLevelCounter > 5)
      goToNextLevel();
   if(LivesCounter == 0)
      loose();
}
```

Comment: Hi,I got an error to say "Access of undefined property e." what is E? thanks

Comment: e is a MouseEvent which is a function parameter. I think I made a mistake when wrote e.x, you should try e.localX, or e.stageX instead.

Comment: hi, I am still getting many errors. 'Access of undefined property e.' for each e. 'Access of undefined property NextLevelCounter.'  'Access of undefined property LivesCounter.'Call to a possibly undefined method loose.' not too sure what to do from here.

Comment: sorry, I thought it was obvious, you need to define those variables, somewhere where you initialize all your variables: 
     var NextLevelCounter:int = 0; 
     var LivesCounter:int = 3; And also you need to make functions for going to next level and loosing, something like these: 
     function goToNextLevel():void{
     trace("gotoNextLevel");
     //logic here
     }
     function loose():void{
     trace("loose");
     //logic here
     }

Comment: sorry, can't make these look nice

Comment: I am slightly confused. Still cannot get it to work, but thank you for your help.